# PC Powers up but does not power mouse or keyboard and no signal to monitor

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I have a pc with an Asrock z77 motherboard, intel i7 CPU, GTX 650 GPU, Crucial 525gb ssd, EVGA 750W power supply, and two sticks of ballistix ram.

I woke up one morning after leaving my PC on overnight, and discovered that the motherboard lights and fans were working, the gpu fan was spinning, but there was no video output and my mouse and keyboard had no power. I restarted the pc but the issue persisted. Since then, I have reset the CMOS several times, tried booting without my gpu, reseating my ram, gpu, and cpu, and tried booting with only 1 stick of ram. None of those things got me any different result than previously mentioned. I even tried booting without ram (at the suggestion of a TomsHardware user) to see if the motherboard beeped (signaling that it was not broken). The board did not beep, however, and the hardware seemed to power up as usual.

I think that this could be caused by a busted motherboard, however I'd like to be able to confirm that before I rush out and buy a new one. I've seen this issue on the forums before, but none of the solutions that worked for those posters have worked for me. I'm pretty fed with this, so any help would be appreciated!

It's also worth mentioning that the Dr. Debug screen on the ASrock mobo displays error 10, which apparently is caused by a cpu issue.

If anyone can help me with this, or help me figure out whether the mobo, cpu, or both are shot, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: The error code indicates a hardware failure.  There is no guarantee it's not the CPU, could be the motherboard, start with cheaper option first

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm going to look into replacing the motherboard. I'll let you know if that fixes it.